# How to get the api usage per key

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-console

I created 2 keys on my account for two applications
Is it possible to have the usage per key to identify which function was most used?
thanks
best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can check the usage per API key (credentials) in the [Google cloud developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard). Select an API you are interested in, in the traffic section of the API overview page select filter by credentials and you should see the corresponding report.

Please have a look at my screenshot.

[image]

I hope this helps!